# How do I find the pitch for the fly press?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, design, mechanisms

To solve the problem first I need to find the pitch of the screw to find the shearing stress, is the stroke 45 degrees per 5.75mm or 90 degrees per 5.75 mm?

[image]

Comment: What distance is stated for the linear movement? How is that related to the rotation angle stated?

Comment: You can treat the thread as a ramp wrapped around the circumference.

Comment: @SolarMike The clearance is 5mm so this is the distance the punch will travel and the no of reveloution is 0.25(90/360) so the answer should be lead=20mm.

Comment: And what about the cutting depth? You need to show what you have considered so far.